Angular 18 httpClient testing expects
I just migrated my app angular version from angular 15 to angular 18.
The app is running ok but my tests starts to fail when i switch the deprecated versions of httpClientModule to provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()), provideHttpClientTesting()
so every expects that i use something like     expect(httpClientSpy.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
is failling now.
Example:
describe('FinishedService', () => {
  let service: FinishedService;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', [
    'get',
    'post',
    'put',
  ]);

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule],
      providers: [
        { provide: HttpClient, useValue: httpClientSpy },
        provideHttpClient(),
        provideHttpClientTesting(),
      ],
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(FinishedService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should update to finished step', () => {
    httpClientSpy.put.and.returnValue(of(void 0));
    const dummyShipmentData = {
      shipmentId: 1,
    };

    service.update(dummyShipmentData).subscribe();

    expect(httpClientSpy.put).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

this test is failling but if i put the deprecated imports HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule, it works.
Is there some new way to expect these htppRequests?
could it be some miss configuration in the .ts itself?
my service.ts constructor:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FinishedService extends BaseService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }

main.ts:
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(
      ...
    ),
    ...
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
  ],
}).catch((err) => console.error(err));


just remove provideHttpClient and provideHttpClientTesting from your test. you aren't using their functionalities and you are providing your own mock

You should probably change the tests to instead of using a Jasmine spy, they use the vanilla Http Test client angular provides.
You will also need the HttpTestingController to build the expectations or to stub API calls. This service provides a comprehensive set of tests and validations (as per above link)
Something like should help you getting started:
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    // ...
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideHttpClientTesting(),
  ],
});
const httpTesting = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  

The problem with the Jasmine Spy usage is that it does not confirm with Angular's life-cycle hooks by itself. You could always make it comply and your tests might start working, but that would be a work around... I believe the proper solution would be to move the tests to be using HttpTestingController.

i solved my issue by runnning the following:
add this at the providers
providers: [
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    provideHttpClientTesting(),
  ],
.....
httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    httpTestingController.verify();
  });

remove all spy and expects and switch for the new version.
like this:
const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(
  `${environment.apiUrl}someendpoint`
);

expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');

req.flush(dummyData);

